# Moment.js - Getting Tomorrow and displaying Its day of the week

Tags: javascript, calendar, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to display time and dates on a site I am working on.

I have a Weather Module that displays TODAY, but I also want to display the forecast for 3 Days forward.
I can use Moment.js to get Tomorrow, Tomorrow + 1 and Tomorrow + 2, but I don't know how to change their format so that it reads "WED, THU, FRI". Here's what I have currently:

```
var today = moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY');
var d1 = moment().add(1, 'days').calendar().format('ddd');
var d2 = moment().add(2, 'days').calendar().format('ddd');
var d3 = moment().add(3, 'days').calendar().format('ddd');
```

The error I get is that `moment(...).add(...).calendar(...).format` is not a funtion.  If I use THIS coode:

`var d1 = moment().add(1, 'days');` and then `console.log()` that variable, I can **SEE**:
`M {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: P, _d: Thu Nov 28 2019 08:51:46 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), …}` So I ***KNOW*** it's available, I just don't know the proper syntax to display the three character label for the day of the week.

Comment: You have simply to remove `.calendar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.calendar()` call, I am not sure why you even need that.

```js
var today = moment();
var d0 = today.format('ddd').toUpperCase();
var d1 = moment(today).add(1, 'days').format('ddd').toUpperCase();
var d2 = moment(today).add(2, 'days').format('ddd').toUpperCase();
var d3 = moment(today).add(3, 'days').format('ddd').toUpperCase();

console.log(d0, d1, d2, d3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```